# how to achieve following expansion panel in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to code this expansion panel, but I can't even adjust its height,  I tried in many ways. I'm first time using this widget please help me out.
thanks :)

this is how I want this

[image]

here is the code I tried. in this code I can't change the height and face other problems too. please check it out.

```
taskTileTest(List<Task> taskLIst, index, context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 30, bottom: 20),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        border: Border.all(width: 0.4),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
            children: taskLIst
                .map((task) => ExpansionPanelRadio(
                      value: task,
                      headerBuilder: (ctx, isOpen) => Row(
                        children: [
                          Checkbox(
                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                            splashRadius: 10,
                            checkColor: Colors.white,
                            fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              Constants.appThemeColor,
                            ),
                            value: task.isDone,
                            onChanged: task.isDeleted == false
                                ? (bool? value) {
                                    context
                                        .read<TaskBloc>()
                                        .add(UpdateTask(task: task));
                                  }
                                : null,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                  width: 200,
                                  child: Text.rich(
                                    const TextSpan(text: 'Task 1'),
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Helvatica_lite',
                                      decoration: task.isDone == true
                                          ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                          : TextDecoration.none,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 4),
                              const Text('Monday | 10:17 pm',
                                  // '${todo.day} | ${todo.time}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      fontFamily: 'Helvatica_lite',
                                      color: Colors.grey))
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      body: Text('ddd'),
                    ))
                .toList()),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

How do I achieve the expansion panel ?

Comment: you want above type of expansiontile widget?

Comment: Try my below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
class ExpansionTileDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpansionTileDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpansionTileDemo> createState() => _ExpansionTileDemoState();
}

class _ExpansionTileDemoState extends State<ExpansionTileDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 6,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
            side: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 0.4,
            ),
          ),
          child: ExpansionTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.today),
            title: Text('ExpansionTile 1'),
            subtitle: Text('Trailing expansion arrow icon'),
            children: <Widget>[

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('Task'),
                  subtitle: Text('Start Devlop......'),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('Task'),
                  subtitle: Text('Start Devlop......'),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  //
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  //
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              )

            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: still, not the main problem isn't solved. how do I change the height of this? I tried wrap in a container with 90 height, but that showed overflow when it expanded. how do I fix that

Comment: can you show that error of overflow ???

Comment: ey it's worked i removed the height parameter, and the expandedtile have padding . its working with that

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        side: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 0.4,
        ),
      ),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.check),
        title: Text('Your Title $index'),
        subtitle: const Text('Monday  |  8.30 PM'),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    horizontalTitleGap: 0,
                    visualDensity:
                        VisualDensity(vertical: -4, horizontal: 0),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    title: Text('Your Title $index'),
                    subtitle: Text('Your Description $index'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    horizontalTitleGap: 0,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    title: Text('Your Title $index'),
                    subtitle: Text('Your Description $index'),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: const [
                      Icon(Icons.edit),
                      Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                      Icon(Icons.delete),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Result-> [image]